# Function for chat refresh and scrolling down to newest messages doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

I've recieved function that should refresh chat box content and it should also scroll down to newest messages. I was using jQuery `load();` for refresh, but it wasn't scrolling down, when I've recieved new message. Than, as I said, I've recieved ajax using function, which should replace my jQuery function. But it doesn't even load the content.

Both codes are below, I am so thankful for every advice, I feel really helpless now...

jQuery load():

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var out = document.getElementById("chat");
    var auto = $('#chat'); 
    var add = setInterval(function() {
        // allow 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        var isScrolledToBottom = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
        console.log(out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight,  out.scrollTop + 1);

        // scroll to bottom if isScrolledToBotto
        auto.load("chat_vypis.php")
        if (isScrolledToBottom)
            out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    },500);
    console.log(add);
    return false; 
});
```

Ajax using:

```
var needsToScrollToBottom=true;
var url='chat_vypis.php';

function updateChat() {
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:'GET',
        success:function(data) {
            var chat=$('#chat');
            chat.html(data);
            if (needsToScrollToBottom) {
                scrollToBottom(chat);
            }
        },
        //even on error, but after the call has completed
        complete:function() {
            setTimeout(updateChat,500);
        }
    });
}

function scrollToBottom(elem) {
    elem.animate({ scrollTop: elem.height() }, "slow");
}
```

Comment: whta exactly happens with the second one

Comment: @epoch nothing - that's the problem. chat content doesn't even load...

Comment: add some logs and see where it stops

Comment: @epoch sorry, I am real begginer at jQuery and that stuff, you mean that `console.log()` ? If you do, I've tried to add 2 that logs, for updateChat and for scrollToBottom, but I have no idea, where to get that log result?

Comment: open up the developer tools in your browser :)

Comment: @epoch ok, I've opened the console, but there was nothing about my function... Screw this chat, really.. :D

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, can you open up the Network tab on the dev tools and see what the request and response of your ajax request is?

Comment: @epoch this is the only thing I've found there:

Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery-1.10.1.min.js:1:0
function scrollToBottom()

Comment: @epoch you can visit the page here: http://mobydyk.cz/s_db_test/ , just click on one of the three pictures and chat window will open

Comment: @op, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

ok, after visiting your page, the main issue seems to be that the button submits the page instead of calling your function.

you need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        // stop the submit
        e.preventDefault();

        // execute your function
        updateChat();
    });
});
```

Comment: but I have to call "send.php" to add the sent message to database, it won't be added with this function, will be?

Comment: ok, I've tried this:
`$(document).ready(function() {
  
    updateChat();
    });` But it throws me to the half of chat box (scrolls to half way to the bottom) and then I've got stuck there. I can't scroll lower and even upper...